# I have an indentationerror: Expected an indented block

Tags: python

hello below is where my code is coming with an issue at line 64 near quiz = difficulty_level(user_level) can anyone help? every time i run this it comes in with this error and for the life of me i cannot figure out what is going on or what is wrong

```
def play():

    quiz = difficulty_level(user_level):
    print
    print quiz

    print "\nYou have only 5 tries best of luck.\n"


    answers_list = relate_answer(user_level)
    blanks_index = 0
    answers_index = 0
    number_of_guesses = 5
    guesses_limit = 0

     while blanks_index < len(blanks):
          user_answer = raw_input("type in your answer for " + blanks[blanks_index] + ": ")
        if check_answer(user_answer,answers_list,answers_index) == "Correct":
            print "nice job! that is the right answer!\n"
            quiz = quiz. replace(blanks[blanks_index],user_answer)
            blanks_index += 1
            answers_index += 1
            number_of_guesses = 5
            print quiz
            if blanks_index == len(blanks):
                print "Congrats"

            else:
            number_of_guesses -= 1
            if number_of_guesses == guesses_limit:
                print "Game over!"
                break
            elif number_of_guesses < guesses_limit:
                print "invalid"
                break
            else:
                print "incorrect try one more time"
                print "You have" + str(number_of_guesses) + "This many guesses left"

play()
```

Comment: Why do you have a colon after your function call? `quiz = difficulty_level(user_level):`  removing that should make python not expect the indentation afterwards

Comment: Are you mixing tabs and spaces?

Comment: I suspect the blanks with no indentation are causing some of the errors, e.g. after `def play():`, blank lines need the same indentation as other statement in the same block. Either add an indentation to the empty line under `def play():` to align with the next line `"    quiz = difficulty_level(user_level.."`, or remove that and other empty lines.

Comment: Tried removing the colon same issue, tried removing that empty line as well and still having an issue i can post the entire code if need be but sorry im pretty noobish to python right now

Comment: @AnilSomani Here's your code formatted so it will run,  although it's missing some function and variable definitions, it will fix the formatting errors you're getting, so you can focus on your program logic and should help you move forward. hope it helps,  https://repl.it/@downshift/SvelteBigheartedCharmap

Answer (score 0):

Change

```py
while blanks_index < len(blanks):
     user_answer = raw_input("type in your answer for " + blanks[blanks_index] + ": ")
    if check_answer(user_answer,answers_list,answers_index) == "Correct":
```

to

```py
while blanks_index < len(blanks):
    user_answer = raw_input("type in your answer for " + blanks[blanks_index] + ": ")
    if check_answer(user_answer,answers_list,answers_index) == "Correct":
```

Comment: Sorry not to sound ignorant but what's the difference?

Comment: In the first example, the `user_answer = ...` line is not at the same indentation level as the next line.  In the second example, it is.  Can you not see that?

Comment: yep just saw it sorry

Comment: still getting the same error under line 63 for indention :(